# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code Index was out of range

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, c#-4.0, datatable

Getting:

> "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>       Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

in

```
if (resD.Tables.Contains(ReDo.TableName))
{
    _result = resD.Tables[ReDo.TableName];
}
```

When I try to execute this code repeatedly, I am getting above exception, though, resD.Table contains the table name specified in condition. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: this is if condition:  
If( resD.Tables.Contains( ReDo.TableName ) ) {
                _result = resD.Tables[ReDo.TableName];
            }

Comment: You have tagged this question with multithreading. Does it mean that you have separate threads that manipulate in some way the resD dataset?

Comment: @Steve, if that method gets called repeatedly because of continuous user interaction then it is throwing the exception, randomly.

Comment: @Silvermind, yes, it was typo, corrected it.

Comment: This could happen only if between if test and the reading of the table some other thread has removed or rebuilt the dataset. Cannot guess what happen in your whole code

Comment: @Steve, if I observe the variable at the time of exception, it shows all data, means it contains that table in it. So just confused why it is happening.

Comment: How do you build the resD dataset? Is the code building the dataset called by more than one thread? You need to add more code to your question. As is it should never fail.

Comment: @Steve, it;s getting updated from multiple locations. Can we put something near "If" condition to avoid unhandled exception? (apart from try, catch)

Comment: @Sachin see *lock* or other synchronization primitives like *Mutex*, *Semaphore*, *ManualResetEvent* etc

Comment: @Eser, it's getting updated from 4-5 places and accessed on atleast 100+ places, so lock may not be convenient.

Comment: @Sachin Who said writing multithreading app is easy...

Comment: @Eser, I am not saying it easy. Just wondering if there any better way to handle it than the conventional lock.

Comment: @Sachin Whatever method you chose, you'll have to update 100+ places in your code...